# Why doesn't ls -al show message queue created by mq_open

Tags: c, linux

I use mq_open to create message queue `/temp.1234`,

1. but command `ls -al` and `ipcs -q`in directory `/` doesn't show any information about the message queue.
2. I use mq_send to send a  message. Also, in another program, mq_open("/temp.1234", O_WRONLY) returns `3`(message descriptor) succesfully, but when calling mq_receive, it outputs **EBADF**. OS is ubuntu.
3. Is it only effective on solaris rather than ubuntu?

**Added**:
it's from unix network programing volume 2.

> Here is the output under Solaris 2.6:
>   solaris % mqcreatel /temp.l234
>   solaris % 1s -1 /tmp/.*l234
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 rstevens otherl 132632  Oct 23 17:08 /tmp/.MQDtemp.1234
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 rstevens other1
>   0 Oct 23 17:08 /tmp/.MQLtemp.l234
>   -rw-r--r--
>   1 rstevens other1
>   0 Oct 23 17:08 /tmp/.MQPtemp.l234

Answer (score 2):

1. The first argument is **not** a filename, it is an identifier only. It will not exist on the filesystem.
2. Attempting to receive from a write-only queue is an error.

Comment: I test `ls -l /temp.1234` according to that book. `ipcs -q `doesn't work as well. Can you tell me a way to inspect message queue with command?